# Is my tom cat attacking my female cat when we're not around?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, aggression, multi-pet-families

I'm just after a bit of advice as I think my tom cat is attacking my female cat when we're not around. My female cat is 4 years old and we've had her since she was a kitten. She was spayed at about 1. We recently rescued the tom cat, around 9 months ago. He is 3 - not sure of the exact age, though; and has been neutered, but again - not sure what age. Although the vet did tell us he was done late because he's big.

When we first introduced them they seemed to get along. They didn't really bother with each other, but would eat together and would always sniff each other nicely. They sometimes had a bit of a scuffle, but never anything nasty, more playful. Just recently, he disappeared for around 6 weeks which is the longest he's been gone. He normally goes for around a week or we would know where to find him. But this time he wasn't where he normally is and was gone for longer. Now, he's back and my female seems really scared of him and won't sleep on the landing with him (like they did before.)

We have been worrying that maybe he is being aggressive when we are out or asleep or even when they are both out. Tonight, she has come home with what looks like a cut on her head, but there's no blood, just a bold white patch (she's jet black.) We're not sure if he's hurt her or if she's done it out. She loves hunting! We really don't know what to do, she's my baby and I hate the thought of her being scared, but don't want to just get rid of our tom...  Any help, please? It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Is your tom cat castrated?
I guess, when he was away for 6 weeks, he wasn't hunting mice, he was hunting female cats. 
Hormones play strange tricks with animals sometimes. If he's not a castrate he needs to feel his domination, as human men )). He wants to be the owner of a territory. In this situation I can see the only option - take him to a vet to castrate him.

Another reason might be a disease. Animals can't talk. They can't tell us that something bothers them. So they start behaving in unusual ways, and aggressiveness is one of them. The solution is the same - take your tom cat to a vet to check his health.

Hope everything will be OK.

Answer (score 1):

He might be attacking her, or he might smell of something weird, or they might have 'forgotten' each other (he's been away for 6 weeks, it's possible). First, try bathing him to rule out the possible smell problem. Then try re-introducing them. If what you did when he first arrived worked fine, just repeat the whole process.